# Preserve the template ID after downloading and uploading a docusign template

Tags: docusignapi

I have been downloading, modifying, and uploading Docusign templates. Every time I run through this process, I get a new template ID, which is a huge problem for me because I need to reference those template IDs in some API calls and do not want to update my code every time a template ID changes.

I have tried using both the the classic Docusign experience which uses XML files as well as the new experience which uses JSON files. Both have the same result, which is that my template IDs get regenerated in spite of being specified in the template file.

Comment: I also really need to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally heard back from Docusign support team after several days, looks like it's not possible:

> > Thank you for contacting DocuSign Support.  When you download and then upload the template into the system, it creates a brand new template ID because it is considered a brand new template.  Even though you are using the code to create a clone of the previous template we can't assign the same template ID to the new template.  This is by design and something we can't change for security reasons.  I hope this gives you some insight and clarity but if you have any questions please feel free to reach out.  Have a great day!
> >
> > Best Regards,
> >
> > AJ
> >     DocuSign Customer Support